# DAX distinct count using different filters in power pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm having a list of orders and orderlines and would like to be able to Count the number of orders by different filters, e.g. by item, payer, warehouse. My issue is that i get the number of lines calculated. I've tried two different methods:

This:

```
=calculate(DISTINCTCOUNT([Ordernumber]))
```

And this other:

```
=calculate(COUNTROWS(SUMMARIZE('TableName';[Ordernumber])))
```

[image: PivotTable]

Comment: The behaviour of the rows looks correct: you have one distinct OrderNumber for the OrderNumber 351532 and orderline 10. The Sum row should show 4 though. Is the Sum row one you have added manually with an Excel formula SUM(D2:D8)? If it is then change your pivot table to show totals instead.

Comment: @Rory, the sum is from the pivot table

Comment: The pivot total should show 4 for DISTINCTCOUNT([Ordernumber]) unless you have filters in your pivot table.

Comment: @Rory, I do have filters in my pivot table, one could be Item another Supplier. It differs, is it possible to get this kind of dynamics into the pivot table.

Comment: I tried to insert the DISTINCTCOUNT[Ordernumber] in the pivottable using by "Insert calculated item" and then it worked